# sorting and pagination cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

in my controller I have this

```
public function station_users($id=null){
        $users = $this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('test_id'=>$this->params['named']['test_id'])));

        $this->set('users', $users);
        $this->render("station_users",'ajax');
    }
```

I am getting all the users for a certain test id but now my sort doesnt work. how can I add pagination.
I tried

```
$this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
```

and that didnt work
thanks

Comment: How did it now work? Are your views set up correctly to handle pagination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `$this->paginate()`, you need to configure your pagination, with something like this:

```
$this->paginate = array
    (
        'User' => array
        (
            'recursive' => 0,
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'test_id' => $this->params['named']['test_id'],
            ),
        )
    );

$users = $this->paginate('User');
```

The [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) is your friend, use it whenever possible.